# Extract XML inside another xml having multiple records

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am pulling clob data from a JDBC server and the below is the sample format of the xml

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crt96.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sales_Posting>
<row>
<ORGANIZATION_ID>1</ORGANIZATION_ID>
<RTL_LOC_ID>269</RTL_LOC_ID>
<POSLOG_DATA>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
        &lt;POSLog xmlns=&quot;http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/&quot;
             xmlns:dtv=&quot;http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/&quot;
             xmlns:xs=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot;
             xs:schemaLocation=&quot;http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/ POSLog.xsd&quot; &gt;
&lt;Transaction xmlns:dtv=&quot;http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/&quot; CancelFlag=&quot;true&quot; OfflineFlag=&quot;false&quot; TrainingModeFlag=&quot;false&quot; dtv:AppVersion=&quot;17.0.0.0.716 - 0.0.0 - 0.0&quot; dtv:TransactionType=&quot;RETAIL_SALE&quot; &gt;
&lt;dtv:OrganizationID&gt;&lt;![CDATA[1]]&gt;&lt;/dtv:OrganizationID&gt;
&lt;RetailStoreID&gt;&lt;![CDATA[269]]&gt;&lt;/RetailStoreID&gt;
&lt;WorkstationID&gt;&lt;![CDATA[2]]&gt;&lt;/WorkstationID&gt;
&lt;/Transaction&gt;
&lt;/POSLog&gt;</POSLOG_DATA>
        <CREATE_DATE>2019-07-17 20:57:56.536</CREATE_DATE>
    </row>
<row>
    <ORGANIZATION_ID>1</ORGANIZATION_ID>
    <RTL_LOC_ID>269</RTL_LOC_ID>
    <POSLOG_DATA>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
        &lt;POSLog xmlns=&quot;http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/&quot;
             xmlns:dtv=&quot;http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/&quot;
             xmlns:xs=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot;
             xs:schemaLocation=&quot;http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/ POSLog.xsd&quot; &gt;
&lt;Transaction xmlns:dtv=&quot;http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/&quot; CancelFlag=&quot;false&quot; OfflineFlag=&quot;false&quot; TrainingModeFlag=&quot;false&quot; dtv:AppVersion=&quot;17.0.0.0.716 - 0.0.0 - 0.0&quot; dtv:TransactionType=&quot;RETAIL_SALE&quot; &gt;
&lt;dtv:OrganizationID&gt;&lt;![CDATA[1]]&gt;&lt;/dtv:OrganizationID&gt;
&lt;RetailStoreID&gt;&lt;![CDATA[269]]&gt;&lt;/RetailStoreID&gt;
&lt;WorkstationID&gt;&lt;![CDATA[2]]&gt;&lt;/WorkstationID&gt;
&lt;/Transaction&gt;
&lt;/POSLog&gt;</POSLOG_DATA>
    <CREATE_DATE>2019-07-18 06:20:38.014</CREATE_DATE>
</row>
</Sales_Posting>
```

I need to pull the xml inside the tag .

For a single record I am able to pull the data using the below code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="/Sales_Posting/row/POSLOG_DATA"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I require it for multiple records.

XSLT 1.0 is preferable. If the result is possible via multiple xslt mappings then that is also fine for me.

Expected Output is :-

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMCwt.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sales_Posting>
    <row>
        <POSLog xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/"
        xmlns:dtv="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xs:schemaLocation="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/ POSLog.xsd">
       <Transaction CancelFlag="true"
                OfflineFlag="false"
                TrainingModeFlag="false"
                dtv:AppVersion="17.0.0.0.716 - 0.0.0 - 0.0"
                dtv:TransactionType="RETAIL_SALE">
      <dtv:OrganizationID>1</dtv:OrganizationID>
      <RetailStoreID>269</RetailStoreID>
      <WorkstationID>2</WorkstationID>
   </Transaction>
</POSLog>
</row>
<row>
    <POSLog xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/"
        xmlns:dtv="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xs:schemaLocation="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/ POSLog.xsd">
       <Transaction CancelFlag="true"
                OfflineFlag="false"
                TrainingModeFlag="false"
                dtv:AppVersion="17.0.0.0.716 - 0.0.0 - 0.0"
                dtv:TransactionType="RETAIL_SALE">
      <dtv:OrganizationID>1</dtv:OrganizationID>
      <RetailStoreID>269</RetailStoreID>
      <WorkstationID>2</WorkstationID>
   </Transaction>
</POSLog>
</row>
</Sales_Posting>
```

I am sharing the image of source structure as well as the expected target structure. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Sales_Posting">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(POSLOG_DATA, '?>')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result must be saved to file before processed further. This is assuming your processor supports `disable-output-escaping`.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Can you please help me to remove the CDATA element in the same xslt?

Comment: You would need to pass the resulting file through another XSL transformation, using another XSLT stylesheet. But why is this necessary? The CDATA sections do not contain any markup (at least not in the given example). Any XML parser will read their contents directly as values.